# Styling camera on React native

Tags: react-native, expo, barcode-scanner

On a screen, I want to scan tickets this way :

```
class Tickets extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Press: false,
      hasCameraPermission: null,
      reference: '',
      lastScannedUrl:null,
      displayArray: []      
    };
  }

   initListData = async () => {
    let list = await getProductByRef(1);
   
    if (list) {
      this.setState({
        displayArray: list,
        reference: list.reference
      });      
    }
    console.log('reference dans initListData =', list.reference)
  };

  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.initListData();
    console.log('reference dans le state =', this.state.reference)

};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionsAsync(); 
  }

  getPermissionsAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === "granted" });
  };

  _onPress_Scan = () => {
    this.setState({
      Press: true
    });
  }

  handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    this.setState({ Press: false, scanned: true, reference: data });
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {reference : parseInt(this.state.state.reference)})
  };

  renderBarcodeReader = () => {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned } = this.state;

    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <Text>{i18n.t("scan.request")}</Text>;
    }
    if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>{i18n.t("scan.noaccess")}</Text>;
    }
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
        }}
      >
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : this.handleBarCodeScanned}
          style={{ flex:1, ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}
        />
        {scanned && (
          <Button
            title={"Tap to Scan Again"}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ scanned: false })}
          />
        )}    
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned, Press } = this.state;
    let marker = null;

  console.log('displayArray', this.state.displayArray, 'reference', this.state.displayArray.reference)
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled style={{flex:1}}> 
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1 }} >
            {Press ? (
              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                {this.renderBarcodeReader()}
              </View>
            ) : (
              <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                <Button
                  color="#F78400"
                  title={i18n.t("scan.scan")}
                  onPress={this._onPress_Scan}>                    
                </Button>
             </View>
            )}
          </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Tickets;
```

This code gives me

[image: screencap]

As you can see I have a top and bottom margin. I would like there to be no space, for the camera to take the entire screen (and for any buttons to be displayed over the camera image)
How can I do it, the style of which element should I change?

Thanks for any help and explanations

Answer (score 1):

can you leave your code for that part? now everything is okay but i believe the image width and height is static and you are not using resizeMode for that image, for camera it will be different .
you can check resizeMode for the camera library you are using

Comment: Hello sir, thanlks for taking the time to answer. This is the screenshot of the emulator. It is not an image integrated in the code it is the camera of the emulator.

Comment: In fact, BarCodeScanner does not allow to use full screen, I used Camera from expo-camera instead and it works fine. ;)